# Advanced Filter generates 1004 Error "Method 'Range' of object' _Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I built an Excel spreadsheet for students to check them in as on time, Late or Sick.

I built a macro through the Developer tab that does an Advance Filter to grab all the "Late" students and copy them to the Late Students sheet.

I set the Range as Columns E through M so that it checks all the columns, compares those columns against a Criteria =Late, then copies to Late Students sheet starting at A1.

```vb
Sub CopyLateStudents()
'
' CopyLateStudents Macro
' Copy Late Students to Late Students Sheet
'

'
    Sheets("Student").Columns("E:M").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("Student!V1:V2"), CopyToRange:=Range("Late Students!A1"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

The Advanced Filter runs the first time I hit OK, but the macro failed with:

> 1004 Error "Method 'Range' of object' _Global' failed

A few pages in this site indicated I need to specify sheets across the code.

Comment: `CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Student").Range("V1:V2")`. `CopyToRange:=Sheets("Late Students").Range("A1")`. I wouldn't put sheet names inside `Range`.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in reviewing this and getting back to your reply.  I implemented your recommendation and it was resolved.  Now I can also write the Sick Students version and call this project solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Student").Range("V1:V2"). CopyToRange:=Sheets("Late Students").Range("A1")
```

Resolves correctly as needed.